# FileProvider.getUriForFile() throwing illegal argument exception (Internal Storage issue)

Tags: android, uri, storage, internal

I believe I have tried almost everything which I have come across but can't get a handle on this error, can someone help please.

My file exists in the folder:

This is how my internal storage looks like
EDITED: UPDATED SCREENSHOT
[Internal storage shows that file does exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvvv9.png)

My code is as follows:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                val uriNew = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@, "com.thatapp.fileprovider", filePDF)
                intent.setDataAndType(uriNew,"application/pdf")
                try{
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch(e:ActivityNotFoundException){
                    val toast =  Toast.makeText(this,"No app found to open the PDF. Please install Adobe Reader",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    toast.show()
                }
```

and the error is as follows:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.thatapp.sitereport/app_Site_20180811_112642/Report_20180811_122857.pdf

and finally my file_paths look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path name="My_Images" path="." />
    <files-path
        name="Files"
        path="/"/>
    <!--external-path name="external_files" path="."/-->

</paths>
```

Comment: Just realised that the two names are different. The 'stored one' and the one used for uri. Going to check why is that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop putting files and directories directly in `/data/data/com.thatapp.sitereport/`. I am not certain how you are doing that. Use `getFilesDir()` on a `Context` and put your files and subdirectories in there. That would equate to `/data/data/com.thatapp.sitereport/files/` (though the exact path will vary by device and user).

At that point, your existing `FileProvider` setup should work.

If you insist on keeping your files in that location, that's your decision, but then you cannot use `FileProvider`, as it does not support serving from there. You would need to create your own `ContentProvider` to serve those files.

Comment: Thanks. I am putting files in sub-directories created under /data/data/com.thatapp.sitereport/